Is sexual love merely a manifestation of human biological needs?
Is sexual love merely a manifestation of human biological needs and natural instincts, or does it transcend to a higher level of human experience where the emotional bond with the other is redefined in a deeper and more profound way beyond physicality?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You ask:

Is sexual love merely a manifestation of human biological needs and natural instincts, or does it transcend to a higher level of human experience where the meaning of existence and connection with the other is redefined in a deeper and more profound way beyond physicality?

To answer your question, the psychological experience of love is more than just a need for reproduction, and we recognize a distinction between being horny and the manifestation of libido and being in love. The nuanced language to describe the difference is difficult to master. Let's take a look at the basics.
The word love and its myriad definitions are a complicated topic in and of themselves. The SEP for instance, starts with an article going all the way back to Plato on the topic. The Ancient Greeks had a variety of attitudes and forms of love some of which the modern post-Christian Westerner might be surprised at, for instance the pederasty of Sparta which is conveniently left out of Hollywood films. A deep analysis of emotions and sexuality is generally undertaken by psychologists, so the philosophy of psychology is relevant to exploring your question.
All facets of love are quite complicated biologically and psychologically. So, your question is quite broad, however, here are a list of SEP articles that might get you on the way to narrowing down the question:

Plato on Friendship and Eros (SEP)
Love (SEP)
Sex and Sexuality (SEP)
Emotion (SEP)

The short answer to your question is that the experience of romantic love is highly interlinked with erotic love, particularly in youth, and is considered quite distinct from platonic love. Limerence is a term that has now become quite popular to describe the initial phase of infatuation at the outset of romantic love. From WP:

Limerence is a state of mind resulting from romantic feelings for another person. It typically involves intrusive and melancholic thoughts, or tragic concerns for the object of one's affection, along with a desire for the reciprocation of one's feelings and to form a relationship with the object of love.

